Can anyone tell me how to get logs of "confirm" transaction not the finalized?
Here is my code:
curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 1,
"method": "getTransaction",
"params": [
"2nBhEBYYvfaAe16UMNqRHre4YNSskvuYgx3M6E4JP1oDYvZEJHvoPzyUidNgNX5r9sTyN1J9UxtbCXy2rqYcuyuv",
"json"
]
}
'
can anyone tell me how to get confirm logs instead of finalized?
with finalized it's work well but it's not working well with confirm transaction.
so i am looking for solution.

You've almost got it, but you need to specify "commitment": "confirmed" in the configuration object, ie:
curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d '
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "getTransaction",
  "params": [
    "2nBhEBYYvfaAe16UMNqRHre4YNSskvuYgx3M6E4JP1oDYvZEJHvoPzyUidNgNX5r9sTyN1J9UxtbCXy2rqYcuyuv",
    {"maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0, "commitment": "confirmed", "encoding": "json"}
  ]
}'

